# How to customize \cite?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

So I have the following papers I need to cite in my thesis:

> Sih, Andrew, Alison M. Bell, J. Chadwick Johnson, and Robert E. Ziemba. 2004. Behavioral Syndromes: An Integrative Overview. The Quarterly Review of Biology 79 (3): 241-277.
>
> Sih, Andrew, Alison Bell, and J. Chadwick Johnson. 2004. Behavioral syndromes: An ecological and evolutionary overview. Trends in Ecology and Evolution 19 (7): 372-378.

Until now, I have used `biblatex` and `\autocite` which gives me

> (Sih, Bell, Johnson and Ziemba 2004) and (Sih, Bell and Johnson 2004).

But I would like to get this

> (Sih et al. 2004a, 2004b)

How do I do that? Preferably without changing

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, authordate, maxcitenames=1, sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's much more helpful to include a small compilable document that shows what you're doing, and for bibliography questions, the `.bib` file entries.  This way people can help you faster. Try adding `uniquename=false` to your `biblatex` options.

Answer (score 1):

The name lists are not both abbreviated to 'Sih et al.' because they are different. That way `biblatex` avoids the (wrong) impression that both papers were written by the same list of authors.

`uniquename=false` as suggested by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557492/how-to-customize-cite#comment1405620_557492) disables that behaviour.

That is, however, not quite enough here. Since `biblatex-chicago`'s `-comp` mechanism that compresses citations from, say, "Knuth 1986a, Knuth 1986b" to "Knuth 1986a, 1986b" relies on the full list of authors and not the *visible* list of authors, the citations will not be compressed. If you want that, you need to modify the citation commands to switch from `fullhash` to `namehash`. Unfortunately, there are about 29 mentions of `fullhash` in `chicago-dates-common.cbx`, so the required code changes would be quite sizeable. Here is a quick workaround that just copies the value of `namehash` to `fullhash` in citations.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, authordate, uniquelist=false, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex-chicago}
\newcommand*{\letfield}[2]{\csletcs{abx@field@#1}{abx@field@#2}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\letfield{fullhash}{namehash}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sih2004:behsynd:int,
  author  = {Sih, Andrew and Alison M. Bell and J. Chadwick Johnson
             and Robert E. Ziemba},
  year    = {2004},
  title   = {Behavioral Syndromes: An Integrative Overview},
  journal = {The Quarterly Review of Biology},
  volume  = {79},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {241-277},
}
@article{sih2004:behsynd:ecoevo,
  author  = {Sih, Andrew and Alison M. Bell and J. Chadwick Johnson},
  year    = {2004},
  title   = {Behavioral Syndromes: An Ecological and Evolutionary Overview},
  journal = {Trends in Ecology and Evolution},
  volume  = {19},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {372-378},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sih2004:behsynd:ecoevo,sih2004:behsynd:int}

\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sih et al. 2004a, 2004b)//(Knuth 1986a, 1986b)]

---

Note that customs styles implementing the bibliography and citation style of particular prescriptive style guide like `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex-apa` are usually not written with customisability (beyond style guide requirements) in mind. If the developers have to balance accuracy in following the rules against customisability, the latter usually loses.

Therefore I usually recommend against trying to modify styles such as `biblatex-chicago`.

In this case I'd also agree with Alan that this particular change can be misleading as it heavily suggests the same set of authors wrote both papers.

Comment: @Merlyn And in all honesty:  "Do not do this." As moewe  say in the opening line, the references are not the same, so it's misleading to combine them in this way.